# Is there an SQL Server equivalent to Oracle's RETURNING statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-returning

Is there an SQL Server equivalent to Oracle's RETURNING statement?

I'm wondering if the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause would help.

Comment: Related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074843/is-there-an-oracle-equivalent-to-sql-servers-output-inserted

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the `OUTPUT` clause is exactly what you need.

In `SQL Server 2008` you can even chain the output clauses.