# Oracle SQL inserting multiple rows and returning something

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

In Oracle, one can insert multiple rows by doing a query like

```
INSERT ALL
   INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val1.1', 'val1.2', 'val1.3')
   INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val2.1', 'val2.2', 'val2.3')
   INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('val3.1', 'val3.2', 'val3.3')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

And with a prepared statement, doing a single insert like this one

```
BEGIN INSERT 
   INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (null, 'val1.2', 'val1.3')
RETURNING column1 INTO ?; END;
```

will result in returning `column1`'s value (supposing there is a trigger assigning a value to it before insert).

Is there a way, if possible at all, to combine both? Meaning, inserting multiple values while still returning all the `column1` values (a resultset) with a single query?

Comment: The [BULK COLLECT INTO](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306%5F01/appdev.102/b14261/tuning.htm#sthref2236) synthax is not supported for INSERT as of 10gR2 (example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074843/is-there-an-oracle-equivalent-to-sql-servers-output-inserted/1075198#1075198)). I've not tested it with more recent versions of Oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423) (at least through the 21c version), one of the restrictions to the returning clause:

> You cannot specify the
> returning_clause for a multitable
> insert.

Comment: perhaps, but there should be way to execute a block and return a resultset of all the single inserts

Comment: if you need the individual returning into values for each insert statement, why not just run them, well, individually?

Comment: I was trying to avoid creating a new query (and request to the db) for every row and use some batch command... I guess a solution would be lock the table, insert every row in a block statement and then sending a query to fetch the new generated keys (the last n inserted rows) and finally unlocking the table. Does this sound right?

Comment: choosing your answer as accepted to close this question. Thanks!

Comment: Multiple insert queries is slow, I agree with Yanick

Comment: As an FYI, you can use FORALL and RETURNING .. BULK COLLECT INTO to do this, but that will mean you have to get your data into a collection before doing your insert, which may or may not be worth the trouble depending on how you are generating these statements.