# Oracle SQL - Inserting multiple rows into multiple tables using the returning values from the first table in the second

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I know about inserting into multiple tables.

But I was wondering if anyone know if there is a way to use the returning values from the first table with the insert in the other table in this multiple table insert?

```
insert all
into table1 (col1, col2, col3) values (param1, param2, param3)
into table2 (col4, col5, col6) values ([table1.returning_id], param5, param6)
select * from source_table;
```

I could solve it with

```
for l_row in l_source_table_cursor loop
  insert into table1 (col1,col2,col3)
  values (param1,param2,param3)
  returning table1_id into l_table1_id;

  insert into table2(col4,col5,col6)
  values (l_table1_id, l_row.param5, l_row.param6);
end loop;
```

But I was wondering if its possible to do it with a multiple table insert statement

Comment: an Oracle SQL question without SQL code is not a nice question. At first glance I would say a TRIGGER

Comment: Sorry, I will try to write an example

Comment: This might can help you: http://allthingsoracle.com/multi-table-insert-statements-in-oracle/

Comment: Something like that @ThomasG

Comment: Please try and search before asking questions, even just this site.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814323/oracle-sql-inserting-multiple-rows-and-returning-something

Comment: @unleashed I searched a lot before I asked a question here, but thank you tho :)