# Alternatives to UPDATE statement Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, performance, oracle11g

I'm currently using Oracle 11g and let's say I have a table with the following columns (more or less)

Table1

- ID varchar(64)
- Status int(1)
- Transaction_date date
- tons of other columns

And this table has about **1 Billion rows**. I would want to update the **status** column with a specific where clause, let's say

```
    where transaction_date = somedatehere
```

What other alternatives can I use rather than just the normal UPDATE statement?

Currently what I'm trying to do is using **CTAS or Insert into select** to get the rows that I want to update and put on another table while using **AS COLUMN_NAME** so the values are already updated on the new/temporary table, which looks something like this:

```
    INSERT INTO TABLE1_TEMPORARY (
        ID, 
        STATUS, 
        TRANSACTION_DATE, 
        TONS_OF_OTHER_COLUMNS)
    SELECT
        ID
        3 AS STATUS,
        TRANSACTION_DATE,
        TONS_OF_OTHER_COLUMNS
    FROM TABLE1
    WHERE
        TRANSACTION_DATE = SOMEDATE
```

So far everything seems to work faster than the normal update statement. The problem now is I would want to get the remaining data from the original table which I do not need to update but I do need to be included on my updated table/list.

What I tried to do at first was use **DELETE** on the same original table using the same where clause so that in theory, everything that should be left on that table should be all the data that i do not need to update, leaving me now with the two tables:

```
    TABLE1 --which now contains the rows that i did not need to update
    TABLE1_TEMPORARY --which contains the data I updated
```

**But the delete statement in itself is also too slow or as slow as the orginal UPDATE statement** so without the delete statement brings me to this point.

```
    TABLE1 --which contains BOTH the data that I want to update and do not want to update
    TABLE1_TEMPORARY --which contains the data I updated
```

What other alternatives can I use in order to get the data that's the opposite of my WHERE clause *(take note that the where clause in this example has been simplified so I'm not looking for an answer of **NOT EXISTS/NOT IN/NOT EQUALS** plus those clauses are slower too compared to positive clauses)*

I have ruled out deletion by partition since the data I need to update and not update can exist in different partitions, as well as TRUNCATE since I'm not updating all of the data, just part of it.

**Is there some kind of JOIN statement I use with my TABLE1 and TABLE1_TEMPORARY in order to filter out the data that does not need to be updated?**

I would also like to achieve this using as less REDO/UNDO/LOGGING as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is a weird question. SQL is a declarative language. Normally, all you should worry about is how to describe what you want. Sometimes the way you formulate your query can have consequences on performance. However, in the case of an extremely simple update statement, how could this possibly be made more effective by reformulating it into something ridiculously complicated? Maybe what you want is implement your own DBMS?

Comment: You didn't describe at all what your problem with the plain update (which looks much more sane than what you're proposing).

Comment: You want to delete millions of rows, and you're complaining that this is slow and it touches the redo/undo log? Of course it is! Of course it does!

Comment: @Mat The plain update is slow. Yes it does work, but I need to make it faster. I'm working with a fixed hardware and timeframe constraint

Comment: Describe "slow". What you describe can't be faster, you're doing a _lot_ more work. And it doesn't look safe at all (transactionaly).

Comment: @popovitsj I'm guessing you never had experience with massive data with a time and resource constraint on executing your query

Comment: @Mat So you're trying to say using CTAS is much slower than massive updates? If that's the case then maybe I should just close this question

Comment: No. CATS can be incredibly faster than an update, _if_ you can do some segment switching after that (partition exchange or table renames or such). If you do a CATS to "extract" what to update, then need to do a complex merge to actually execute the update, you're toast - the merge will be essentially as expensive as the plain update itself. If you can't do partition-wise magic (ctas/exchange), you _might_ be able to try parallel updates - but there's a load of restrictions on that, no idea if it would work in your case.

Comment: @Mat I'm already over the process of extracting the data to update and updating it. The only problem now is that its now on another table leaving all the other data that didn't need to be updated on the original table mixed with the data that supposedly should be updated. I'm now thinking of using a primary key on the temporary table to compare with the original table, I hope this works

Comment: So instead of a "simple" update, you are now going to have do update the exact same rows, but drive the update from a join to another table. What makes you think this is going to be faster than the original update?

Comment: @Mat I think I'm explaining this incorrectly. I don't plan to do a "re-update" to my original table based on the temporary table. I want to eliminate the data on the original table leaving only the data that was not part of my where clause, while of course avoiding the use of not equals, not in, not exist. I think doing an "INSERT" would be much faster but I first need to filter out what to insert from my original table or do it the other way around and get rid of the duplicate rows on the original table

Comment: @Mat but if you're saying that doing the ordinary "UPDATE" is faster than this, then so be it.

Comment: How do you plan on making the updated data available in the original table then? Insert /*+ append */? That might very well wreck a some of your indices and queries. And the delete is about as expensive as an update. You're back to your initial problem, except you've scanned the data twice instead of once (plus the temp table creation).

Comment: (Oh, and the delete+insert at the back will gradually turn your table into cheese (full of holes) which will increase your storage requirements and decrease your cache efficiency.)

Comment: @Mat okay I see your point. I was planning to rebuild my objects after this, but okay Im going back to my original update statement

Comment: What if you deleted the rows from your original table and used the [bulk collect into](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074843/is-there-an-oracle-equivalent-to-sql-servers-output-inserted) to funnel the output into your other table? Not an oracle person but I've used the equivalent in SQL Server with some success

Comment: How about using an analytic approach? Why don't you post the execution plans for the different statements? Without that you are only wasting your time with a lot of trials and the results might be even misleading because cashing effects

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is not a one-time operation, but you are trying to design for a repeatable procedure.

Partition/subpartition the table in a way so the rows touched are not totally spread over all partitions but confined to a few partitions.

Ensure your transactions wouldn't use these partitions for now.

Per each partition/subpartition you would normally UPDATE, perform CTAS of all the rows (I mean even the rows which stay the same go to TABLE1_TEMPORARY). Then EXCHANGE PARTITION and rebuild index partitions.

At the end rebuild global indexes.

If you don't have Oracle Enterprise Edition, you would need to either CTAS entire billion of rows (followed by ALTER TABLE RENAME instead of ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION) or to prepare some kind of "poor man's partitioning" using a view (SELECT UNION ALL SELECT UNION ALL SELECT etc) and a bunch of tables.

There is some chance that this mess would actually be faster than UPDATE.

I'm not saying that this is elegant or optimal, I'm saying that this is the canonical way of speeding up large UPDATE operations in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

How about keeping in the `UPDATE` in the same table, but breaking it into multiple small chunks?

```
UPDATE .. WHERE transaction_date = somedatehere AND id BETWEEN 0000000 and 0999999
COMMIT
UPDATE .. WHERE transaction_date = somedatehere AND id BETWEEN 1000000 and 1999999
COMMIT
UPDATE .. WHERE transaction_date = somedatehere AND id BETWEEN 2000000 and 2999999
COMMIT
```

This could help if the total workload is potentially manageable, but doing it all in one chunk is the problem. This approach breaks it into modest-sized pieces.

Doing it this way could, for example, enable other apps to keep running & give other workloads a look in;  and would avoid needing a single humungous transaction in the logfile.