# INSERT OUTPUT Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ssis

In a SSIS package I build, I need to capture the output of a update clause in Oracle, in order to send a warning email

I have read the related question [Is there an Oracle equivalent to SQL Server's OUTPUT INSERTED.*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074843/is-there-an-oracle-equivalent-to-sql-servers-output-inserted) But it doesn't give me a proper result set, that I can capture through a Execute SQL task

```
DECLARE
TYPE ra_InfoErrorMail is RECORD
(LFUKID Crpdta.F580002.LFUKID%TYPE
,LFAA10 Crpdta.F580002.LFAA10%TYPE
,LFJOBDETLS Crpdta.F580002.LFJOBDETLS%TYPE);
TYPE ta_InfoErrorMail is  TABLE OF ra_InfoErrorMail;
t_InfoErrorMail ta_InfoErrorMail;

BEGIN
UPDATE CRPDTA.F580002 SET LFKY = 'ERROR' WHERE LFAA10 = 'MYPROJECT' AND LFUSER ='MYUSER'
RETURNING  LFUKID,LFAA10,LFJOBDETLS   BULK COLLECT  INTO t_InfoErrorMail;


--SELECT LFUKID,LFAA10,LFJOBDETLS FROM t_InfoErrorMail t; -- this doesn't work


END;
```

How do I get the whole t_InfoErrorMail in a neat SSIS-capturable ResultSet ?

Comment: Thanks Johan Buret.  I wondered if you have tried compiling `ra_InfoErrorMail` and `ta_InfoErrorMail` as persistent object types via `CREATE TYPE...`, and then  `... RETURNING RA_INFOERRORMAIL(LFUKID,LFAA10,LFJOBDETLS) BULK COLLECT INTO t_InfoErrorMail ...`?

Comment: Could you just have a select statement in an `Execute SQL` task before your update statement? You could just `select blah  WHERE LFAA10 = 'MYPROJECT' AND LFUSER ='MYUSER' ` and then have an `execute sql` task that does the update?