# How can I SELECT uncommitted records within the same transaction?

Tags: sql, oracle, typeorm

I'm using OracleDB with TypeORM on Sveltekit.

I want to SELECT records that were updated before commit in the same transaction. However, regardless of whether the transaction `ISOLATION LEVEL` is set to `SERIALIZABLE` or `READ COMMITTED`, the records that can be retrieved by SELECT will be old records.

SELECT is running immediately after UPDATE in TypeORM's SQL log.
I can select correctly if I do an explicit commit after the update.
How can I retrieve the last written record?

**(September 28 Edit)**
It seems that my post was wrong. very sorry.
With .Net Core 6 + C# 10 + Oracle, I was able to UPDATE a record and SELECT before commit to get the updated record.
However, with node.js + Sveltekit + TypeORM, even if I did the same thing as above, I got the old record before the update.
I want to select new records in the same way on the node.js side.

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: _"I want to SELECT records that were updated before commit in the same transaction"_ - it sounds like you're trying to do something like triggers or auto-auditing, [in which case you just need the `RETURNING` clause for `INSERT`/`UPDATE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074843/is-there-an-oracle-equivalent-to-sql-servers-output-inserted).

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do this from a third-party application.

Use `PL/SQL` and do it all in a single block:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_ids SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST;
BEGIN
  UPDATE table_name
  SET    value = 'something'
  WHERE  other = 'something else'
  RETURNING id BULK COLLECT INTO v_ids;

  OPEN :your_cursor FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   table_name
    WHERE  id IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_ids));
END;
/
```

If you want you can wrap it in a procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE update_table_name(
  i_new_value IN  TABLE_NAME.VALUE%TYPE,
  i_other     IN  TABLE_NAME.OTHER%TYPE,
  o_cursor    OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
  v_ids SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST;
BEGIN
  UPDATE table_name
  SET    value = i_new_value
  WHERE  other = i_other
  RETURNING id BULK COLLECT INTO v_ids;

  OPEN o_cursor FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   table_name
    WHERE  id IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_ids));
END;
/
```

Then call the procedure from TypeORM.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6frK_CGA)